# Send data form modal window Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i am developing an application over Sharepoint 2010, I am using ECMAScript Client Object Model, so from one applications page using SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options) I am openning another page. From this second page I want to send the information the user inserts back to the parent page.  HOw can I do this?.

Thanks a lot for any comments !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass callback function in options of the showModalDialog method. This callback function takes two parameters, a dialogResult and a returnValue of type object that can contains any data. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058.aspx

When you close your modal dialog with method commonModalDialogClose you can pass result and object parameters and use them in your callback function in the parent window.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff409682.aspx